# Why does DRF consider only PUT and POST

Tags: django-rest-framework

I understand this question might be considered opinion-based, and still I would like to receive explanation regarding this.

The question is, why does DRF consider only 'PUT' and 'POST' methods when populating the `actions` sections ? When I ask "why", I mean what is, in your opinion, the possible philosophy behind this decision ?

This is their source code:

**venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/metadata.py**

```
def determine_actions(self, request, view):
    """
    For generic class based views we return information about
    the fields that are accepted for 'PUT' and 'POST' methods.
    """
    actions = {}
    for method in {'PUT', 'POST'} & set(view.allowed_methods):
        view.request = clone_request(request, method)
        try:
            # Test global permissions
            if hasattr(view, 'check_permissions'):
                view.check_permissions(view.request)
            # Test object permissions
            if method == 'PUT' and hasattr(view, 'get_object'):
                view.get_object()
        except (exceptions.APIException, PermissionDenied, Http404):
            pass
        else:
            # If user has appropriate permissions for the view, include
            # appropriate metadata about the fields that should be supplied.
            serializer = view.get_serializer()
            actions[method] = self.get_serializer_info(serializer)
        finally:
            view.request = request

    return actions
```

UPD:
Notably, it is strange that the DRF thinks that PATCH is unnecessary.

Comment: I would guess it is because `patch` is just `post` with `partial=True`, and the same code is called for both.  Other than that, I can't see a particular reason.  This is just for the `options` request, and there are no standards for that.  I should add, I find it odd too.